# What's wrong with my array initialization in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Why is this a syntax error in ruby?

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

servers = [ 
            "xyz1-3-l" 
    ,       "xyz1-2-l" 
    ,       "dws-zxy-l" 
    ,       "abcl" 
]

hostname_input = ARGV[0]
hostname = hostname_input.gsub( /.example.com/, "" )
servers.each do |server|
    if  hostname == server then 
            puts "that's the one"
            break
    end
end
```

... when I execute this script I get this output ...

```
$ ./test.rb abc1
./test.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ']'
        ,       "xyz1-2-l" 
         ^
./test.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting $end
        ,       "dws-zxy-l" 
         ^
```

... if I simply put everything on the same line its ok ...

```
$ cat test.rb 
#!/usr/bin/ruby

servers = [ "xyz1-3-l" ,        "xyz1-2-l" ,    "dws-zxy-l" ,   "abcl" ]

hostname_input = ARGV[0]
hostname = hostname_input.gsub( /.example.com/, "" )
servers.each do |server|
        if  hostname == server then 
                puts "that's the one"
                break
        end
end
$ ./test.rb dws-zxy-l
that's the one
```

Comment: Well that's the error then, no? Where the comma goes?

Comment: commas go at the end of the line, not at the beginning.

Comment: You don't need this sort of contortion in Ruby, trailing commas are ignored.

Comment: @muistooshort: Wait, what? I was about to be shocked to discover that I hadn't noticed in seven years of writing Ruby that trailing commas are ignored in arrays, so I tried writing one without them, and…syntax error. Did you mean something else?

Comment: @Chuck: Works for me with `a = [1,2,3,]` and even with newlines mixed in. Or did you do `[1,2,3,,]`?

Comment: @muistooshort: Oh, I thought you meant *all* trailing commas were ignored (i.e. at the end of any line), so you could define arrays with no commas. Never mind me.

Comment: @Chuck: That was my next guess :) Too many languages with too many slightly different comma rules.

Comment: Not related to the question, but you can replace the somewhat complex block with `puts "that's the one" if servers.include? hostname` and if the data you're searching through is more complex than simple strings, you could do `server = servers.find { |server| server == hostname }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look ma, no commas (or quotes):

```
servers = %W[
    xyz1-3-l
    xyz1-2-l
    dws-zxy-l
    abcl
]

# => ["xyz1-3-l", "xyz1-2-l", "dws-zxy-l", "abcl"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Newlines are significant in Ruby. You need to put the comma at the end of the line or use a backslash before your newline to indicate that the line is continuing (of course, in that case, what's the point in moving the comma to the next line?).

Comment: leading commas mean you can comment out a line without them being off by one. In the OP's case, training commas will work fine, too, but for things like options hashes, leading comma is nice because then you can delete or comment out the line, without having to edit the lines around it.